# trying to have my GUI give an error message when one of the fields are not put in?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

trying to have my GUI give an error message when one of the fields are not put in ? im struggling to see how to do have a message pop up when one of the fields are not put in but when they are all put in then it works.

```
from numbers import Number
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

def enter_data():
    accepted = accept_var.get()

    if accepted=="Accepted":

        Cardnumber = Card_number_entry.get()
        Year = Year_entry.get()
        Name = Name_entry.get()
        Set = Set_entry.get()
        Cert = Cert_entry.get()
        Grade = Grade_entry.get()
        print("Card Number:", Cardnumber)
        print("Year:", Year)
        print("Name:", Name)
        print("Set:", Set)
        print("Cert:", Cert)
        print("Grade", Grade)
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title= "Error", message="You have missed out infomation")

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("MGC POPULATION REPORT")

frame = tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

card_info_frame =tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Card Infomation")
card_info_frame.grid(row= 0, column=0, padx=40, pady=20)

Card_number_label = tkinter.Label(card_info_frame, text="Card Number")
Card_number_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=1)
Year_label = tkinter.Label(card_info_frame, text="Year")
Year_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=1)
Name_label = tkinter.Label(card_info_frame, text="Name")
Name_label.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=1)
Set_label = tkinter.Label(card_info_frame, text="Set")
Set_label.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=10, pady=1)
Cert_label = tkinter.Label(card_info_frame, text="Certification (#)")
Cert_label.grid(row=8, column=0, padx=10, pady=1)
Grade_label = tkinter.Label(card_info_frame, text="Grade")
Grade_label.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=10, pady=1)

Card_number_entry = tkinter.Entry(card_info_frame)
Year_entry = tkinter.Entry(card_info_frame)
Name_entry = tkinter.Entry(card_info_frame)
Set_entry = tkinter.Entry(card_info_frame)
Cert_entry = tkinter.Entry(card_info_frame)
Grade_entry = tkinter.Entry(card_info_frame)
Card_number_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
Year_entry.grid(row=3, column=0)
Name_entry.grid(row=5, column=0)
Set_entry.grid(row=7, column=0)
Cert_entry.grid(row=9, column=0)
Grade_entry.grid(row=11, column=0)

button = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Enter Data", command= enter_data)
button.grid(row=13, column=0, sticky="news", padx=20, pady=10)


window.mainloop()
```

so if anyone can help me that would be helpful thank you

Comment: Could you provide a little more insight on the problem you are having? What error occurs on which line, and what are your inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: possibly helpful or related [Showing a MessageBox error whenever an entry box is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59082823/1248974)

Comment: thanks @BRemmelzwaal for the reply it is saying this : Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mills\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\mills\source\repos\MGC POP REPORT\MGC POP REPORT\MGC_POP_REPORT.py", line 7, in enter_data
    accepted = accept_var.get()
NameError: name 'accept_var' is not defined

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken thank you but im not very good at coding lol so even tho the solution is probs there i cant tell where to put it lol

Comment: Where is `accept_var` defined?

Comment: @jordanmills, also try replacing your `else:` line with `if '' in [Cardnumber, Year, Name, Set, Cert, Grade]:
            messagebox.showwarning('Warning', 'You have missed out infomation')`

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken thing is i dont know where to put any of this lol

Comment: @jordanmills with the code you posted, replace lines 23-24 with the two lines I posted in last comment

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken nope still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the text boxes are empty.

For example:

```
if not Card_number_entry.get() or not Name_entry.get() or not Set_entry.get() or not Cert_entry.get() or not Grade_entry.get():
    accepted = "Error"
else:
    accepted = "Accepted"
```

If any of the textboxes have no content, the if statement will return true.